# Any Android tablet with the NEON instruction set?

Tags: android, android-ndk, arm, neon

I am interested in the [unofficial port of VLC for Android with NEON instructions](http://www.zeropaid.com/news/95996/unofficial-vlc-player-for-android-pre-apha-released/):

Even if Android smartphones with the NEON instruction set do exist, I have not been able to spot any NEON-powered Android tablet. Is there any such Android table available for sale in Europe?

Answer (score 5):

To be exact, it's the 7inch Galaxy Tab.

The newer, 10.1 inch version features Tegra2 which is NEON-less.

I would avoid purchasing any device with Tegra anyway.

What is nVidia thinking, omitting NEON on a Coretext based CPU? That sucks.

Answer (score 3):

[Galaxy tablet 7"](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Samsung-Galaxy-7-inch-Bluetooth-Android/dp/B0042D75TU) runs on ARM Cortex-A8 which fully supports NEON instruction set, and is quite a good developer device. There might be other tablets available in Europe that I don't know about. In general, any ARM Cortex A8 and up processor will support NEON.

Comment: @Tisys - I made a quick research on the topic and could find only Galaxy among branded Tabs. Sony have some mobile phones running on cortex-a8. Please accept the above answer if that is what you were looking for or respond to the post.

Answer (score 1):

The HTC tablets (Flyer, EVO View) use a Qualcomm chip which supports NEON also.

Answer (score 1):

Look for SYSCHECK in the Google Play store as an Android app to check a particular tablet for features including NEON set.

Answer (score 0):

The Arnova 8 G2 has NEON:

```
Processor   : ARMv7 Processor rev 2 (v7l)
BogoMIPS    : 1004.66
Features    : swp half thumb fastmult vfp edsp thumbee neon vfpv3 
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant : 0x3
CPU part    : 0xc08
CPU revision    : 2

Hardware    : RK29board
Revision    : 0000
Serial      : 0000000000000000
```

The Arnova 7c G2 does not:

```
Processor   : ARMv6-compatible processor rev 5 (v6l)
BogoMIPS    : 163.57
Features    : swp half thumb fastmult vfp edsp java 
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 6TEJ
CPU variant : 0x1
CPU part    : 0xb36
CPU revision    : 5

Hardware    : QCT MSM7x27 SURF
Revision    : 0000
Serial      : 0000000000000000
```